# Spectrum of received signal from radar fm-cw

Tags: spectrogram, radar, linear-chirp

I obtained actual data from a researcher, consisting of a matrix composed of several received signals from an up-ramp fm-cw radar.

Wouldn't be reasonable to plot the spectrogram of a ramp up and obtain a chirp like this ? (This is from MATLAB spectrogram examples)

[image]

Instead what I get is this (I know the plots are rotated):

[image]

I have read that the received signal if you send a triangular wave, should be a the same but delayed and shifted in frequency.

What do you think?

Comment: Add more detail to your problem. How did you obtain the received signal ?
Also, the frequencies of 0 to 500 Hz are unlikely, are they excursions around an unspecified carrier frequency ? Otherwise, yes, you should theoretically obtained a time-shifted chirp (time shift represents distance to target) and frequency-shifted (freq. shifted represents speed of target)

Comment: Well, I obtained them from a dataset given me by a researcher and the ramps were already separated. The first Image is just an example obtained from matlab website to explain what I would expect from the results so I don't know about the frequencies.

Comment: well, ask your researcher what you've actually got; we can only guess. My guess is that you've received the beat frequency signal, not the baseband-converted RF signal, and in that case, everything's fine.

Comment: What's the beat frequency signal? Is it the difference between sent and received spectrogram?

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro it's the signal after downmixing with the TX LO. You should probably brush up your basic knowledge of how classical FMCW radars work if this is news to you!